# assign the result of an list operation to var

Tags: python

In python,

how can i do something like that

```
a = ["pera", "uva", "maca", "saladamista"]
b = a.reverse()
```

but without assign the reverse list to `a`?

Comment: That snippet doesn't "assign the reverse list to a", it calls the list's `reverse` method which mutates the very same list object `a` refers to. [Confusing variables and objects](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) is easy but harmful.

Comment: no, because with the [:], b is a **copy** of a, not a **reference** to it, so you call b's reverse, after making it's value the same as a.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers: I wasn't commenting on sinan's suggestions (which is not a comment but an answer by the way) but on OP's confused statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First copy the list, then reverse the copy:

```
a = ["pera", "uva", "maca", "saladamista"]
b = a[:]
b.reverse()
```

or use the "Martian smiley":

```
b = a[::-1]
```

**Edit**: In case someone is interested in timings, here they are:

```
In [1]: a = range(100000)

In [2]: %timeit b = a[:]; b.reverse()
1000 loops, best of 3: 436 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit b = a[::-1]          
1000 loops, best of 3: 414 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit b = list(reversed(a))
1000 loops, best of 3: 823 us per loop
```

Comment: how does this "martian smiley" works? Do you have a link for that concept? thank you for the answer. I was looking to the simple way to do that.. the way python programmers prefer and the most readable.

Comment: @Pabluez: Have a look at [this answer by Alex Martelli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705670/best-way-to-create-a-reversed-list-in-python).

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
b = list(reversed(a))
```

Comment: Should be `list(reversed(a))` if you want `b` to be a list.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Good catch - I just noticed that too :)