# for loop nested inside the expression from an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a question about syntax more than anything. I am pretty sure that I am almost right, but not quite. I'm trying to put a for loop inside of the expression for an if statement.

A mock-up of what I think it should be for a simple palindrome tester:

```
toTest = "asdffdsa"
if toTest[i]==toTest[-i] for i in range(len(toTest)/2):
    print("It's a palendrome!")
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: I did look through that, however there isn't an example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you mean

```
if all(toTest[i] == toTest[-i] for i in range(len(toTest)/2)):
    print("It's a palindrome!")
```

Note that it would be much easier to do

```
if toTest == toTest[::-1]:
    print("It's a palindrome!")
```

Comment: Thanks! You just answered my question AND taught me a new keyword. Does the "-1" in "toTest[::-1]" reverse the list?

Comment: @Mokolodi1: Yes, it reverses the string, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3705676/279627.

Comment: Not a keyword; `all` is a function.

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be exactly what you're looking for, here is a short-hand to check if a string is a palindrome in Python:

```
toTest = "asdffdsa"
if toTest == toTest[::-1]: print ("It's a palindrome!")
```