# How do you enter a list as a parameter without defining what the length of the list will be?

Tags: python

For example, here's a function that takes 5 arguments and reverses the order

```
def reverseList(a,b,c,d,e): 
    normalList = [a,b,c,d,e] 
    reverseList = reversed(normalList) 
    printedList = [] 
    for eachit in reverseList:
        printedList.append(eachit)

    print "This is the list that was entered: %r" % (normalList)
    print "This is the same list, but in reverse: %r" % (printedList)
```

I'm new to this, so I can't figure out how to enter a "custom" list, e.g. not limit how many numbers can be entered in the function.

Comment: You can use `*args`, but in this case, I'd recommend just passing in a list...

Answer (score 3):

Just pass a list and return a list of the function reversed:

```
>>> def reverseList(li):
...    return list(reversed(li))
... 
>>> reverseList(['a', 'b', 'c'])
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Works with a list of any length.

---

Or, as pointed out in comments:

```
>>> def reverseList(li):
...    return li[::-1]
```

---

If you are looking for support for a [variable length of arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) rather than a list, use `*args` with the 'splat' `*` meaning your function is taking a tuple of unknown length (rather than named positional arguments):

```
>>> def reverseArgs(*args):
...    return args[::-1]
... 
>>> reverseArgs('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('d', 'c', 'b', 'a')
```

Comment: use li[::-1] . best way to [reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705670/best-way-to-create-a-reversed-list-in-python)