# Mysterious interaction between Python's slice bounds and "stride"

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, slice

I understand that given an iterable such as

```
>>> it = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I can turn it into a list and slice off the ends at arbitrary points with, for example

```
>>> it[1:-2]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

or reverse it with

```
>>> it[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

or combine the two with

```
>>> it[1:-2][::-1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

However, trying to accomplish this in a single operation produces in some results that puzzle me:

```
>>> it[1:-2:-1] 
[]
>>>> it[-1:2:-1] 
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
>>>> it[-2:1:-1]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

Only after much trial and error, do I get what I'm looking for:

```
>>> it[-3:0:-1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

This makes my head hurt (and can't help readers of my code):

```
>>> it[-3:0:-1] == it[1:-2][::-1]
True
```

How can I make sense of this? Should I even be pondering such things?

---

FWYW, my code does a lot of truncating, reversing, and listifying of iterables, and I was looking for something that was faster and clearer (yes, don't laugh) than `list(reversed(it[1:-2]))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because in a slice like -

```
list[start:stop:step]
```

`start` is ***inclusive***, resultant list starts at index `start`.

`stop` is ***exclusive***, that is the resultant list only contains elements till `stop - 1` (and not the element at `stop`).

So for your case`it[1:-2]` - the `1` is *inclusive* , that means the slice result starts at index `1` , whereas the `-2` is *exclusive* , hence the last element of the slice index would be from index `-3`.

Hence, if you want the reversed of that, you would have to do `it[-3:0:-1]` - only then `-3` would be included in the sliced result, and the sliced result would go upto `1` index.

Comment: I guess what this means is that "stride" really wasn't in the minds of the designers when they though about slice syntax (which has some conveniences, to be sure).

Comment: Yea, I believe this could be a good read for that, not completely related to slicing, but does mention that - http://python-history.blogspot.in/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html

Answer (score 6):

The important things to understand in your slices are

- Start will be included in the slice
- Stop will **NOT** be included in the slice
- If you want to slice backwards, the step value should be a negative value.

Basically the range which you specify is a half-open (half-closed) range.

---

When you say `it[-3:0:-1]` you are actually starting from the third element from the back, till we reach `0` (not including zero), step one element at a time backwards.

```
>>> it[-3:0:-1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Instead, you can realize the start value like this

```
>>> it[len(it)-3 : 0 : -1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]` is what I'm looking for, not `[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]` — i.e., `it[1:-2][::-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other two answers disambiguate the usage of [`slicing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) and give a clearer image of how its parameters work.

---

But, since your question also involves ***readability*** -- which, let's not forget, ***is a big factor especially in Python*** -- I'd like to point out how you can improve it slightly by assigning `slice()` objects to variables thus removing all those hardcoded `:` separated numbers.

Your truncate and reverse slice object could, alternatively, be coded with a usage implying name :

```
rev_slice = slice(-3, 0, -1)
```

In some other config-like file. You could then use it in its named glory within slicing operations to make this *a bit* more easy on the eyes :

```
it[rev_slice]  # [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

This might be a trivial thing to mention, but I think it's probably worth it.

Comment: Any idea on how performance of `slice` with a stride compares with `list` + `reversed`?

Comment: Hm, this has been adressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705670/best-way-to-create-a-reversed-list-in-python) so linking to this answer is the right thing to do (instead of just copying the contents). Additionally, as mentioned in the comments you'll have to make a tradeoff between readability and slight speed performance. If you have really large arrays, why don't you tackle this with good ol' numpy?

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a function for readability:

```
def listify(it, start=0, stop=None, rev=False):
    if stop is None:
        the_list = it[start:]
    else:
        the_list = it[start:stop]
    if rev:
        return the_list[::-1]
    else:
        return the_list

listify(it, start=1, stop=-2)  # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
listify(it, start=1, stop=-2, rev=True)  # [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to intuitively understand the Python slicing syntax is to see how it maps to the corresponding C `for` loop.

A slice like

```
x[a:b:c]
```

gives you the same elements as

```
for (int i = a; i < b; i += c) {
  ...
}
```

The special cases are just default values:

- `a` defaults to 0
- `b` defaults to `len(x)`
- `c` defaults to 1

Plus one more special case:

- if `c` is negative, then `a` and `b` are swapped and the `<` is inverted to a `>`

Comment: Your statement that "`a` and `b` are swapped" in the negative step case seems very misleading. I think you mean that the default values are swapped, but that's not quite true. The default start value for a reversed slice is `-1` and the default end value is `-len(x)-1`. You can't specify that end index with a positive number, if you start at `len(x)-1` and try counting down, the end index will be `-1`, which means something different.

Comment: @Blckknght: Good point. My mental model usually only thinks about the positive case. I'm not sure how best to articulate the negative case here.

Comment: Hmm, looking in [the cpython source for `list` slicing](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/listobject.c#l2415), I see it doesn't directly use `stop` at all in the C `for` loop, but rather uses the computed number of items that will be in the slice and just counts that many items while incrementing an index variable by `step`. The [code for slice objects](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/sliceobject.c#l246) that does the length calculation has `if (step < 0)` checks all over the place.

Comment: It might be more useful to think in Python, rather than `C`. Except where negative or (otherwise out of bounds) start or stop values are concerned, `x[start:stop:step]` is a lot like `[x[i] for i in range(start, stop, step)]`. You can get exactly correct handling of the edge cases by using a `slice` object and calling its `indicies` method with the length of our list to get the parameters for `range`: `[x[i] for i in range(*slice(start, stop, step).indicies(len(x)))]`