# Trying to print vertically in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create an image that needs to be printed vertically:

[image]

From the for loop, I can print a image fine by indenting to a new line; however, I want the image to rotate counter clockwise 90 degrees (Is this transpose?).

I tried to use `from itertools import zip_longest` but it gives:

> TypeError: zip_longest argument #1 must support iteration

```
class Reservoir:
    def __init__(self,landscape):
        self.landscape = landscape
        self.image = ''
        for dam in landscape:
            self.image += '#'*dam + '\n'

        print(self.image)

landscape = [4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2]  
lake = Reservoir(landscape)
print(lake)
```

Comment: Where's the code causing the error?

Comment: Please provide more information in the way the code relates to the error, and actually state what your question is.

Comment: hi guys, It is my first time posting in python so I do not know how I can print my output

Comment: I placed my image there which it suppose to look like. I am very sorry that I am not used in using stackoverflow. Please bear with me

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you will find a function or a lib that do that for you. But you can code this rotation by hand.

You don't want to display a real image here, but to print chars that represents a landscape. You have to print the "image" line by line, but since your landscape array represents the number of '#' you want in each *column*, you have to loop over the total number of lines you want, and for each char in that line, print a ' ' or a '#' depending on the corresponding landscape column value

With

```
h = max(landscape)
```

you calculate the total number of lines you want to print by finding the max of the landscape values.

Then, you loop over theses lines

```
for line in reversed(range(h)):
```

in that loop, `line` takes values 6, 5, 4, etc.

For each line, you have to loop over the whole landscape array to determine, for each column if you want to print a space or a '#', depending on the value of the landscape column (`v`) and the current `line`

```
for v in self.landscape:
    self.image += ' ' if line >= v else '#'
```

The full program:

```
class Reservoir:
    def __init__(self, landscape):
        self.landscape = landscape

        h = max(landscape)

        self.image = ''
        for line in reversed(range(h)):
            for v in self.landscape:
                self.image += ' ' if line >= v else '#'
            self.image += '\n'

landscape = [4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2]
lake = Reservoir(landscape)
print(lake.image)
```

The result:

```
                 #            
                ###       #   
#               ###      ##   
##              ###   ######  
####           ###############
######       #################
```

Comment: This is a fantastic information Antwane! Thank you! Regarding how stackoverflow works, How can I format the result like the way you did?? I can't seem to figure out how you did that. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Another question, how does the reversed function works here? Does it work like counting backward such as list[:-1]?

Comment: To format the result, you can use a [code or preformatted text block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), similar to what you used to post the python sample code in your question

Comment: [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) is a python built-in. It reverses the sequence given as argument and returns an iterator. reversed() return a lazy-evaluated iterator, so it is a better option here, because we only need the inverted list in the for loop. If you had to re-use the resulting list in the rest of the code, you should use `the_list[::-1]` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3705670/1887976)