# Is this a correct way to implement bubble sort?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

Is this a correct way to implement bubble sort?
I get a sorted list, but I have a doubt that the method is correct.

```
# Input unsorted list
size_lis = int(input("enter the size of the list"))
size = 0
list1 = list()

while (size < size_lis):
    element = int(input("enter the element"))
    list1.append(element)
    size += 1

# Sort
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    for j in range(0, len(list1)-1):
        if list1[j] > list1[j+1]:
            list1[j],list1[j+1] = list1[j+1],list1[j]

print(list1)
```

Comment: Does it work? Then it's correct

Comment: Yes it works But is it the correct way to implement the bubble sort.

Comment: What do you mean by correct? If the program does it's job, why would it be incorrect? Are you looking for a more pythonic, more succinct, more elegant solution?

Comment: No just wanting to do it in the correct way.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by the correct way. Please define what you mean by correct. 
If it works, it's correct - why is your script not correct? What's incorrect about it?

Comment: you try and implement bubble sort and compare it with mine.

Comment: OK, I just did. Mine works too. Is mine correct?

Comment: Actually bubble sort generally use a for loop inside a while loop (with a boolean changed in the if). The advantage is that you save some iterations, since you stop as soon as it is sorted (the obvious example is if it's sorted at start, you only do one iteration). It's not about the 'correct' way, just a slightly more efficient, even if the word efficient doesn't really fit with bubble sort.

Comment: Improved wording and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is the *correct implementation* of the bubble sort algorithm. But you can prevent extra loops using this kind of implementation:

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr))[::-1]:
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            if arr[j - 1] > arr[j]:
                arr[j], arr[j-1] = arr[j-1], arr[j]
```

First loop iterating through `range(len(arr))` in reversed order (`[::-1]` - operation for reversing the list in the most efficient way). After first iteration of this loop the biggest element in your list will be placed in the end of the list. And the second loop needs to iterate only through remaining elements.

I tested yours(`bubble_sort_2`) and mine(`bubble_sort`) implementation using two identical arrays on 1000 elements.
Here are the results (using *cProfile*):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.215    0.215    0.215    0.215   bs.py:22(bubble_sort_2)
    1    0.128    0.128    0.128    0.128   bs.py:16(bubble_sort)
```

As you can see, `bubble_sort` is faster than `bubble_sort_2`.

Comment: Rather than slicing your `range` to reverse it, why not just create it in the desired order in the first place? If you use `range(len(arr), 0, -1)`, you can even get rid of the `i+1` in the `range` call for `j`. (`reversed` is also an efficient way to iterate on something in reverse.)

Comment: @Blckknght, if you're talking about readability - you're right. But for further examination of this question I recommend you to read answers on this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705670/best-way-to-create-a-reversed-list-in-python)

Comment: *If* you were reversing some pre-existing list, I'd agree that the martian-smiley would probably be the fastest way to get the job done (though it's probably faster than the alternatives by an insignificant amount). However, you're creating the list right there in the `range` call, so there's no possible way that reversing it afterwards is going to be faster than just creating it in the correct order to start with.

Comment: @Blckknght, if we're talking about python-2.x yours list creation will be more effective. But in the case of python-3.x objects iterated over are lazy. (I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617160/reverse-the-list-while-creation) for the explanation).

Answer (score 1):

In bubble sort the largest element is moved step by step to the end of list. Thus after first pass there is this one element in its final position. The second pass should sort only N-1 remaining elements, etc.

In the posted code, just adjust the inner circle like this. That'll save almost 50% of CPU time.

```
n = len(lst)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
        if lst[j] > lst[j+1]:
            lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1],lst[j]
```