# Reverse the list while creation

Tags: python, performance, list, memory

I have this code:

```
def iterate_through_list_1(arr):
    lala = None
    for i in range(len(arr))[::-1]:
        lala = i

def iterate_through_list_2(arr):
    lala = None
    for i in range(len(arr), 0, -1):
        lala = i
```

Logically, iterating through list created by `range()` in reverse order should be more efficient, than creating list with `range()` and reversing it afterwards with `[::-1]`. But *cProfile* tells me, that `iterate_through_list_1` function works faster.

I used python-3. And here you can see output of profiling on the two identical arrays with 100000000 elements in them.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   1    5.029    5.029    5.029    5.029    bs.py:24(iterate_throgh_list_2)
   1    4.842    4.842    4.842    4.842    bs.py:19(iterate_throgh_list_1)
```

What happened underneath Python slices while list creation?

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x? What are the numbers, what's the timing difference? How did you test it? Did you run multiple iterations of it?

Comment: The second function is *much* more obvious.  Prefer it unless there is a *massive* advantage - and it makes a difference to your application.

Comment: @MartinBonner if that's perfect, what about `for obj in reversed(arr)`? Or if you really need indicies, `for idx, obj in enumerate(reversed(arr))`?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski, thank you for improving my question. I've added more description

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski: Yes indeed, both of those look better still although the enumerate version will return the index *in the reversed list*, so it will go 0,1,2 (not 2, 1 0) for a three element list.

Comment: @MartinBonner `reversed(enumerate(arr))` if perfectly fine.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski `reversed(enumerate(arr))` didn't work for me: TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence - python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well designed test shows that first function is slowest on Python 2.x (mostly because two lists have to be created, first one as a increasing range, second one as a reverted first one). I also included a demo using `reversed`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import timeit

def iterate_through_list_1(arr):
    lala = None
    for i in range(len(arr))[::-1]:
        lala = i

def iterate_through_list_2(arr):
    lala = None
    for i in range(len(arr), 0, -1):
        lala = i

def correct_iterate_reversed(arr):
    lala = None
    for obj in reversed(arr):
        lala = obj


print(sys.version)
print('iterate_through_list_1', timeit.timeit('iterate_through_list_1(seq)',
                                              setup='from __main__ import iterate_through_list_1\nseq = range(0, 10000)',
                                              number=10000))
print('iterate_through_list_2', timeit.timeit('iterate_through_list_2(seq)',
                                              setup='from __main__ import iterate_through_list_2\nseq = range(0, 10000)',
                                              number=10000))
print('correct_iterate_reversed', timeit.timeit('correct_iterate_reversed(seq)',
                                                setup='from __main__ import correct_iterate_reversed\nseq = range(0, 10000)',
                                                number=10000))
```

Results:

```
2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:05:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)]
iterate_through_list_1 3.87919592857
iterate_through_list_2 3.38339591026
correct_iterate_reversed 2.78083491325
```

Differences in 3.x are all neglible, because in each case objects iterated over are lazy.

```
3.5.2 (default, Jul 28 2016, 21:28:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)]
iterate_through_list_1 2.986786328998278
iterate_through_list_2 2.9836046030031866
correct_iterate_reversed 2.9411962590020266
```