# Check special symbols in string endings

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check special symbols such as `!?,().` in the words ending? For example `Hello???` or `Hello,,` or `Hello!` returns `True` but `H!??llo` or `Hel,lo`  returns `False`.

I know how to check the only last symbol of string but how to check if two or more last characters are symbols?

Comment: If you want `'H!??llo'` to return `True` then I think you really want to check if any special symbols appear in your string, not just end with them.

Comment: Why do you are about "two or more"? From your example, inspecting the last character is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to use regex for this.

```
import re

def checkword(word):
    m = re.match("\w+[!?,().]+$", word)
    if m is not None:
        return True
    return False
```

That regex is:

```
\w+          # one or more word characters (a-zA-z)
[!?,().]+    # one or more of the characters inside the brackets
             #   (this is called a character class)
$            # assert end of string
```

Using `re.match` forces the match to begin at the beginning of the string, or else we'd have to use `^` before the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
word = "Hello!"

def checkSym(word):
    return word[-1] in "!?,()."

print(checkSym(word))
```

The result is:

```
True
```

Try giving different strings as input and check the results.

In case you want to find every symbol from the end of the string, you can use:

```
def symbolCount(word):

    i = len(word)-1
    c = 0
    while word[i] in "!?,().":
        c = c + 1
        i = i - 1

    return c
```

Testing it with `word = "Hello!?."`:

```
print(symbolCount(word))
```

The result is:

```
3
```

Comment: `word[len(word-1]` is just `word[-1]`. Negative indexing goes from the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
string="gffrwr."
print(string[-1] in "!?,().")
```

Comment: The OP said that they already know how to check only the last character.

Comment: But my answer still does what the examples in the question say

Comment: `For example Hello??? or Hello,, or Hello! returns True but H!??llo or Hel,lo returns False.`

Comment: Good point. I decided to revoke my downvote since the question is ambiguous, but I can't since the window for doing so has closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a count of the 'special' characters at the end of a given string.

```
special = '!?,().'
s = 'Hello???'

count = 0
for c in s[::-1]:
    if c in special:
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print("Found {} special characters at the end of the string.".format(count))
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `s[::-1]` syntax does? It seems fairly obvious, but I've never seen it before.

Comment: It gets the list 's' and returns a shallow copy starting from the last element and ending at the first.
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705670/best-way-to-create-a-reversed-list-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "Hello???"
if re.findall('\W+$', s):
   pass
```