# Function calling li.reverse() vs reverse(li)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am new in python.

```
>>>li=["a","b","c"]
>>>li.reverse() 
>>>li
 ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

How we got an idea that we have to call function like this `li.reverse()` not like this `reverse(li)`.
Similarly on other function

```
sorted(li,reverse=True)
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Here Why we can't call it `li.sorted(reverse=True)`?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705670/best-way-to-create-a-reversed-list-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python are relevant

Comment: Because `reverse` is a method of list data-structure, while `sorted` is a builtin method (Not specific to any module or data-structure). You need to consult python official documentation to locate the right method and its correct usage.