# Python : Calling functions from inside another function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python so please excuse the layman description.

**Question :** Given a sentence, return a sentence with the words reversed

**My Solution:**

```
def sentence_reverse(text):
    a = text.split()
    a.reverse()
    return ' '.join(a)
```

**Output:**

```
sentence_reverse('I am home') --> 'home am I'
sentence_reverse('We are ready') --> 'ready are We'
```

the code works the way it is supposed to but my question is, why can't i make a function call directly from the returned result of the previous function. i,e

why can i not do something like

return ' '.join(text.split().reverse())

this would work just fine in java since i get List object from text.split() to which, i would operate on with the reverse() function which would return me the inverted list which would then be used by the join() to make this list into a string.

This, is also something that i have tried:

text.split() returns a List, and applying .reverse() function on it **SHOULD** return the elements of the same list in reverse order, but when i execute this line,`print(text.split().reverse())`, i get `None`

Comment: you can just look into `.reverse`. It does not return anything or returns none. `.reverse` reverses the list in place.

Comment: Also, you can look into comparison of different reverse methods in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705705/5916727

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `reverse` returns None, and updates the list, so so None is not valid for `join`.

Yeah so `reverse` is `inplace` function so no way to fix that.

So Use `reversed`:

```
return ' '.join(reversed(text.split()))
```

Or `[::-1]`:

```
return ' '.join(text.split()[::-1])
```

From docs:

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default None. [1] This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

---

> After code example.
>
> > https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2):

> which would return me the inverted list ..

Here's the problem. In Python, calling `list.reverse()` doesn't **return** the reversed list. It just reverses it in place.

What you need is:

```
return " ".join(text.split()[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.reverse` You can use python list iterator to reverse:

```
me = 'ready are We'
" ".join(me.split()[::-1])
>>> 'We are ready'
```